# How can I avoid redundant string in JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, list

I am new to JSON and I am stuck with below question. How can I optimize a JSON object to use less `'id','Data','Time'` strings to save space?

```
{
"MyData":
[
  {"id":"1","Data":"Point1","Time":"Time1"},
  {"id":"2","Data":"Point2","Time":"Time2"},
  {"id":"3","Data":"Point3","Time":"Time3"},
  {"id":"4","Data":"Point4","Time":"Time4"},
  {"id":"5","Data":"Point5","Time":"Time5"},
  {"id":"6","Data":"Point6","Time":"Time6"},
  {"id":"7","Data":"Point7","Time":"Time7"}
]
}
```

I am expecting somethings like

```
{
"MyData":
[
  {"1","Point1","Time1"},
  {"2","Point2","Time2"},
  {"3","Point3","Time3"},
  {"4","Point4","Time4"},
  {"5","Point5","Time5"},
  {"6","Point6","Time6"},
  {"7","Point7","Time7"}
]

}
```

But I see people use first method more. Why is it so? What's the disadvantage of the second method?

Comment: is this a json object?? ***{"1","Point1","Time1"}***

Comment: well use array instead of object i suppose... `[
  ["1","Point1","Time1"],
  ["2","Point2","Time2"], ...
]`

Comment: The bottom isn't valid JSON. If you want an array, go for it!

Comment: @ggorlen: My JSON validator says it's valid. I am using linter-jsonlint in atom.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: I check it with JSON validator before writing and it didn't give me any error. So I suppose.

Comment: All, It seems that my validator was giving incorrect output. On analysis on net now I think I go with array of array approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSON follows a key-value structure. What you could do is to store each of the values in a single array, always following the same order, such as:

```json
{
  "MyData": [
    ["1","Point1","Time1"],
    ["2","Point2","Time2"],
    ["3","Point3","Time3"],
    ["4","Point4","Time4"],
    ...
  ]
}
```

However, IMHO, if you do this you are losing the JSON's strengths, which allows you to structure the data and easily access it in a readable way, instead of relying on indices.

Comment: I think this could be the best approach with my current knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "MyData": [
  ["1","Point1","Time1"],
  ["2","Point2","Time2"],
  ["3","Point3","Time3"],
  ["4","Point4","Time4"],
  ["5","Point5","Time5"],
]}
```

or

```
[
  ["1","Point1","Time1"],
  ["2","Point2","Time2"],
  ["3","Point3","Time3"],
  ["4","Point4","Time4"],
  ["5","Point5","Time5"],
]
```

or simply :
`["1","Point1","Time1", "2","Point2","Time2", "3","Point3","Time3", "4","Point4","Time4", ...]`

Answer (score 0):

since this is not a valid json: `{"1","Point1","Time1"},`

the best that you can do is reformat the schema definition of the json

```
{
"MyData":
    [
      "1": {"Point": "Time"},
      "2": {"Point": "Time"},
      "3": {"Point": "Time"},
      "3": {"Point": "Time"},
       ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: I understand that he also wants to have the "Points" as information, you would need to have "Point1", "Point2"..., not a single key named "Point".

Comment: and point1 ist the element at index "1"... so the data matches..